# How to convert string to datetime without seperator using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, converters

How to convert this string to Datetime

20180227105954636241

```
select CONVERT(datetime, '20180227105954636241', 120)
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert varchar to datetime on SQL Server with custom format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453936/convert-varchar-to-datetime-on-sql-server-with-custom-format)

Comment: I know, I can do this using substring method, But this is not right way I think. I wish to answer instead of giving negative points.

Comment: In order for your question then to be better, it's much more appreciated, if you included that link in your question, saying that you know about that way and proving why do you think this is not the right way and you're looking for another way. I *think* that this would have given you actually positive points instead of negative.

Comment: It may be "obvious" to you but you ought to spell out clearly what datetime you expect that string to produce. It's usually also good to include more than one example. I can apply an interpretation on that string that seems obvious to *me* but how are we to know if our interpretations match yours?

Comment: I suggested the STUFF function, but regardless of the method- you could incorporate the solution into a VIEW that puts this into the correct format. Then you don't have to worry about the particular implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert these patterned string to `datetime` directly and i don't see any use of `CONVERT` function for this purpose. You can just format the string like below to `cast` it :

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(MAX) = '20180227105954636241'
DECLARE @date1 VARCHAR(30) 

set @date1 = SUBSTRING(@date,  1, 8) + ' ' +  -- this is datepart
             SUBSTRING(@date,  9, 2) + ':' +  -- this is hour
             SUBSTRING(@date, 11, 2) + ':' +  -- this is minute
             SUBSTRING(@date, 13, 2) + '.' +  -- this is second
             SUBSTRING(@date, 15, 6)          -- this is decimal of second

select cast(@date1 as datetime2(6))  -- 6 is the decimal point of second
```

**Output**

```
2018-02-27 10:59:54.636241
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your question, I can suggest use SUBSTRING Method and parse NVARCHAR values and then convert it to DATETIME.

```
DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(MAX) = '20180227105954636241'

DECLARE @year NVARCHAR(4) = SUBSTRING(@date,0,5)
DECLARE @month NVARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(@date,5,2)
DECLARE @day NVARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(@date,7,2)
DECLARE @hours NVARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(@date,9,2)
DECLARE @minutes NVARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(@date,11,2)
DECLARE @seconds NVARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(@date,13,2)
DECLARE @milliseconds NVARCHAR(2) = SUBSTRING(@date,15,3)

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, (@Year + '-' + @month + '-' + @day + ' ' + @hours + ':' + @minutes + ':' + @seconds + '.' + @milliseconds), 120)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `STUFF` function to insert the necessary colons, periods, and dashes.  STUFF takes 4 parameters.  First is the string to stuff chars into, second is the position within the string, third is the number of chars to delete (always 0 in this example), fourth is to char to insert.

After stuffing, this results in a string 26 chars long but the convert to datetime only accepts 23 chars.  You have to take the `LEFT` 23 of this value, cutting off the last 3 chars of the string to convert to the datetime datatype.

```
DECLARE @temp varchar(100) = '20180227105954636241'
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(@temp, 15, 0, '.'), 13, 0, ':'), 11, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ' '), 7, 0, '-'), 5, 0, '-'), 23), 120)
```