# Date Conversion from ISO format to normal format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to convert ISO formatted date into normal format date in SQL. But I am getting the same error like below

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Here is the date I am trying to convert. I tried replacing T as well but no luck. I even tried with casting, different date formats. Format function works only with date datatype.

```
DECLARE @stringDate nvarchar(50)
SET @stringDate = '20191230T095931.331'

SELECT 
    @stringDate AS StringDate,
    CONVERT(datetime2, @stringDate, 126) AS ConvertedDate
```

Input date is in this format `'20191230T095931.331'` and I would like to have it in 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:fffff' format.

Can anyone please help me to convert this date format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to datetime without seperator using sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004451/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-without-seperator-using-sql)

Comment: The issue is that the separators are missing from the date varchar. Therefore, I think the only option is to split the character up and concat it again with the appropriate separators. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49004451/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-without-seperator-using-sql

Comment: That is a "normal" format for a limited audience. ISO is in fact the "normal" format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically there is *no* good reason to force a date format within a database. This should always be done in the presentation layer (a database has no presentation layer, only client tools). Your requirement and approach indicate you might misunderstand something. If you could give us some background on why you want to do this we could clarify.

If you just want an answer, try this

```
DECLARE @stringDate nvarchar(50)
SET @stringDate = '20191230T095931.331'

DECLARE @ISOString VARCHAR(50)
SET 
@ISOString = 
-- Date portion
LEFT(@stringDate,4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@stringDate,5,2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(@stringDate,7,2) +
-- Time portion
SUBSTRING(@stringDate,9,3)+':'+SUBSTRING(@stringDate,12,2)+':'+SUBSTRING(@stringDate,14,2)+RIGHT(@stringDate,4)

SELECT 
    @stringDate AS StringDate,
    @ISOString As ISOFormatString,
    CONVERT(DATETIME,@ISOString,126) As IAmADate,
    FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME,@ISOString,126),'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss:fffff') IAmAString
```

Comment: thank you very much . this works.  We work on equities data and this data comes from trading desk.. they have certain datetimestamp which is stored in this format.. we have to convert it into required format for reporting purpose

Comment: If this data is going into a database, I strongly suggest you store it using the correct data type, and that is `DATETIME`. Then you can order it, perform date arithmetic on it, format it how you like, and not have to worry about ambiguous formats.

Comment: yes i am doing it as datetime that is why wanted this to be converted into this format. Thank you very much Nick.